# Show Subtitles using Qt6 multimedia module

Tags: multimedia, qt6, qtmultimedia

I was looking at QT6 Qml media player example and I want to display subtitles in the video using a .srt file. Is it possible to do so and if not, is there any other way I can display subtitles for the video